# What is Doctrine default behavior for saving empty strings from POST? I would like to save NULL values

Tags: codeigniter, orm, doctrine, http-post, codeigniter-3

I am saving some values coming from a form (managed by CodeIgniter) into simple Doctrine entities. Some of my fields are optional.

Sample code of controller :

```
$entity->setDistance($this->input->post('distance'));
$entity->setKilometricRate($this->input->post('kilometric_rate'));
$this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
$this->getEntityManager()->flush($entity);
```

When I don't fill some fields in the form, then 0 is persisted into the database (since php converts "" in 0).

Sample code of entity :

```
/**
 * @var float|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="distance", type="float", precision=53, scale=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $distance;

/**
 * @var float|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="kilometric_rate", type="float", precision=53, scale=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $kilometricRate;
```

Is there a way to tell Doctrine to save `NULL` value instead of `0` or empty string, without testing all the strings in all the setters?

At the moment I am using a custom helper, but I am quite sure that there is a better way to do this.

Helper :

```
public function getValueOrNull(?string $postedVal):?string{
    if ($postedVal==="0") return "0";
    return (!empty($postedVal) ? $postedVal : null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple places where you can tackle this. For example you could check how CodeIgniter handles forms and ensure that an empty fields returns null instead. I don't know CI well enough to say how easy it is and where this could cause side effects.

You could also deal with this in your entities making sure that whenever someone sets a value with an empty string it is converted to null:

```
class MyEntity
{

    // ...

    public function setDistance($distance)
    {
        if ($distance === '') {
            $distance = null;
        }
        $this->distance = $distance;
    }
}
```

If you want to always want to have this for floats you could create a custom type that extends float and modify the method `convertToPHPValue`. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types

Comment: Unfortunately, Codeigniter does not have an `empty_data` replacement mechanism like in Symfony, and optional empty fields are always sent as '' instead of NULL in Symfony. I would like to avoid to edit my numerous setters (for strings and numbers (float or int)). I am quite sure there is a way to avoid this in Doctrine and/or Codeigniter

Comment: Yes, see the link at the bottom. In that case you should probably create a custom DBAL-type for your entities and/or overwrite the existing float type with your custom type.